# Multiple isolated gazebo on same PC(ROS2)

Tags: ros2, gazebo-11, gazebo-ros

I need to run multiple instances of gazebo on same PC (ROS version foxy) and want to interact with them individually like spawning a robot in one of them.
I tried using different ROS_DOMAIN_ID in different terminal and run

```
ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py
```

But when i launch the command in second terminal its gzserver is automatically killed.
My main aim is to run navigation stack by using one of the gazebo world and make the robot in other gazebo world to mimic the same by publishing the same /cmd_vel values to it. Both robots are identical but with different namespaced topics and nodes.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an old answer on answers.gazebosim [How to open several gazebos in a linux operating system?](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15897/how-to-open-several-gazebos-in-a-linux-operating-system/) answered by a user named @chapulina.

I am pasting the answer below:

> To run various Gazebo instances, you must make sure each of them is using a different port. You can set this with the `GAZEBO_MASTER_URI` environment variable.
>
> It's also convenient to run Gazebo in verbose mode so you can read error messages.
>
> For example, on one terminal, start `gzserver` on the default port (11345):
>
> ```
> gzserver --verbose
> ```
>
> You'll see the port printed in green:
>
> ```
> [Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
> ```
>
> Then on a new terminal, open `gzclient`:
>
> ```
> gzclient --verbose
> ```
>
> You'll see the same port printed in green:
>
> ```
> [Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
> ```
>
> If you try to start another gzserver on a new terminal, without changing the URI, you'll get an error:
>
> ```
> [Err] [Master.cc:96] EXCEPTION: Unable to start server[bind: Address already in use]. There is probably another Gazebo process running.
> ```
>
> The correct way is to open a new terminal and start another instance with a new URI:
>
> ```
> export GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11346; gzserver --verbose
> ```
>
> This time the URI is different:
>
> ```
> [Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11346
> ```
>
> And then on a new terminal, the respective gzclient:
>
> ```
> export GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11346; gzclient --verbose
> ```
>
> And you should also see the same URI:
>
> ```
> [Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11346
> ```

Hope it helps someone else with same issue.

Comment: Please block quote format all quoted text

Answer (score 0):

When you do `ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py`, and it kills the gzserver, that sounds to me like behaviour that should be expected. IIRC, Gazebo attaches itself to the port localhost:11345. The next instance, *i.e.*, the next time you launch the gazebo launch file, this would kill the server that is running on the above mentioned port. Take a look at what the [gazebo.launch.py](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/79fd94c6da76781a91499bc0f54b70560b90a9d2/gazebo_ros/launch/gazebo.launch.py#L26) does - it launches both the server and the client, unless otherwise specified.

You can try launching one `gzserver` instance, and multiple clients, and see if that solves your problem. You can take a look at the official gazebo docker image, but if you are going to use it with ROS 2, it is not too difficult to create your own image, and spawn multiple containers from that one image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i found an old answer here. So, what needs to be done is to 

``` 
export GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=localhost:<port_number> 
``` 

Now, different gzserver will run at different ports.

Comment: That's great ! I'd suggest you to edit your original post to include this information as an update for anyone who might have the same problem.

Comment: I added it as answer.